# Implementing Flajolet–Martin algorithm in Python

Tags: algorithms, hash, python, hashing, streaming-algorithm

**I am stuck on what to do.**

I am trying to create a simple implementation of the **[Flajolet–Martin algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flajolet%E2%80%93Martin_algorithm)** using Python. The stream will be the contents of a text file and you will produce an approximation of the number of unique words in the file as given by the algorithm. You will need to process the file one line at a time and may not store any part of the file. You can obtain words by splitting the lines on whitespace. Your code will be run from a terminal according to the following command

The **text file** is:

```
this is a fun file
this is the second line of the file
this is the third line of the file
this is the fourth and final line of the file
```

**Code**

```python
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        bin_string = bin(hash(word))
        print(bin_string)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't help you with programming exercises.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! It might be a surprise to you that your question is off-topic. This site focuses on the theory behind programming, not on programming using a particular language or software. Please see our [help on topic](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Your question might be on-topic on [SO].

Comment: 0) gather specifications of input, output and additional information, here: the algorithm named 0.9) find a name for what to implement 1) write [*and document*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring) a dummy of what to implement 2) write a test that your implementation works as specified. Run it: It should fail. 3) Given an algorithm, include its description in the dummy as comment 4) implement 5) While not satisfied with test & result 5.1) While not satisfied with test, improve test 5.2) While not satisfied with result, improve implementation

Answer (score 0):

The objective is to estimate the cardinality of a multiset M, where M is the set of words in the file, using a small amount of storage.  The probabilistic counting algorithm in the [Flajolet-Martin 1985 paper](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/FlMa85.pdf) requires a hash function whose output is sufficiently uniformly distributed over the set of all $L$-bit strings, and works as follows. A big string BITMAP[0..L-1] is initialized to all zeros. For each word w in the multiset, hash(w) is computed, and an index i is determined, where i is the position of the least significant 1 in the binary representation of hash(w).  (The pseudocode below assumes the function rho computes this index $i$.)  Then, BITMAP[i] is set to 1. After a pass through all elements of the multiset $M$, the quantity $R$ is computed and is the position of the leftmost zero in BITMAP.  An estimate of the number n of distinct elements in the multiset is $n \approx \frac{2^R}{\psi}$, where $\psi = 0.77351$.

Here's the pseudcode (I'll leave you to implement the code below, including the functions rho and hash, in Python):

```
for i = 0 to L-1:
    BITMAP[i] = 0
for word in M:
    i = rho(hash(word))
    BITMAP[i] = 1
R = smallest i such that BITMAP[i] = 0
n = 2^R / 0.77351  #estimate of number of distinct elements in M
```

The intuition is that if $n$ is the number of distinct elements in the multiset $M$, then BITMAP[0] is accessed about $n/2$ times, BITMAP[1] is accessed about $n/4$ times, and so on, and so if $i >> log_2 n$, then BITMAP[i] will be 0 with high probability, and if $i << log_2 n$, then BITMAP[i] will be 1 with high probability, and there will be a fringe of 0's and 1's for $i \approx \log_2 n$.  The authors suggest using the position of the left-most zero or right-most 1 in BITMAP to obtain the estimate $R$ (they propose using the former, and some of the other literature suggests using the latter).

Comment: Just in case you have not realized yet, it is frowned upon to answer a question that is off-topic, since it will encourage people to post off-topic questions. No experienced users will upvote answers to off-topic question in general.

Comment: Off-topic-ness is also the reason why I am planning to reject your edit on the question if the question has not been deleted nor migrated after a week, although your edit improves the question greatly. (Of course, others may still approve your edit.)

Comment: @JohnL.  I don't agree the OP's question is off-topic. It's a very interesting and topical question on streaming/data mining algorithms.

Comment: OK, it is certainly possible you are right that this question is not off-topic. I will wait and see the asker's response before I change my standing. The asker can approve your edit, anyway, regardless of off-topic or not.

Comment: @JohnL. It's quite clear from the post that the asker doesn't know the F-M algorithm in the first place (so the question doesn't seem to be about just how to implement a given algorithm in Python).  So I gave a pseudocode.  The asker can take it from there.  Some people might find it difficult or intimidating to read a paper themselves and arrive at the pseudocode.